# Is there are an option to fold my code in Rider?

Tags: c#, ide, jetbrains-ide, rider

Is there are an option to fold my code in Rider?

At least right now I do not see it, so is it possible to enable it in settings somehow?

[image]

I mean something like an arrowhead.

Going to Editor | General | Code Folding does not help at all. Here are my default settings:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Code_Folding.html Found by Googling for `folding in rider c#`

Comment: wow, i have never thought of that as code folding, more like collapsible code blocks,  you learn something new every day

Comment: Goto Editor | General | Code Folding in JetBrains Rider settings and enable it.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, thank you, but it does not help. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue. Here is the support ticket that was updated 5 days ago:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-10523 that succeeds https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-15648

Answer (score 1):

In addition to having the correct things checked in `File | Settings | Editor | General | Code Folding`, what worked for me was ALSO going to `File | Settings | Editor | Inspection Settings` and ticking `Enable code analysis`, and magically all my code folding arrows appeared and syntax highlighting started working.

Answer (score 0):

It is a JetBrains bug. That is because according to [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Code_Folding_Settings.html) the folding should work once you go to `File | Settings | Editor | General | Code Folding`, but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue with the code folding was caused by [turned off code analysis for large files](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010996600-Rider-Cannot-Analyze-a-Source-File-Because-It-s-Too-Large). The fix was to click 'OFF' text in the top-right corner and to choose highlighting of 'All Problems'.